# Ещё один нюанс на разных устройствах и версиях Android

Tags: java, android, sms

Всем привет!
Выбираю SMS из хранилища телефона

```
String[] SMS = { "person", "thread_id", "address", "body" };
c = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), SMS, null, null, "date DESC");
```

И вот что обнаружилось

1) "Samsung galaxy ace" Android 2.3.5 и "Alcatel" Android 2.3.6.

Значения полей person (идентификатор контакта) и thread_id (идентификатор потока сообщения) всегда для всех SMS равны null, даже для смс, номера которых содержатся в контактах телефона.

2) "HTC Desire C" Android 4.0.3 - честно возвращает адекватные значения указанных полей.

Задача в том, чтобы связать смс с контактом и отобразить имя отправителя.

Можно связывать по номеру телефона в принципе, но это достаточно ресурсоемкая и длительная процедура, тормозит, короче, сильно.

Однако же сами аппараты отображают в смс имена контактов. Т.е. либо приложение по какой-то причине не может получить доступ к этим полям, либо надо пользовать какие-то другие(???)...

Кто знает в чём может быть дело?

**Поправочка**

С thread_id - это я сам лажанулся, он на всех телефонах возвращается. А вот person только на HTC.
Для HTC связка person - contact_id работает. 
а вот что делать для тех телефонов, где person==null ???

Спецом (для отсечки собственной криворукости :) )запустил стороннюю прогу, которая детали sms-сообщений выводит, она тоже person показывает равным null на самсунге и алкателе.

Проверил, thread_id не подходит для прямой связки смс и контакта.

Подскажите, как быть, плиз!

Comment: Что ты лажаешь часто...

Comment: не ошибаются тока покойники :)
а конкретно что подсказать можешь по организации связи с контактлистом?

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что `contact_id` - это плохой референс, поскольку он может меняться в зависимости от разных обстоятельств. Где-то в доках написано, что им не рекомендуется пользоваться для связки контакта с другими данными. Единственный надежный референс это номер телефона, но с ним тоже есть проблема. Несколько контактов могут иметь одинаковый номер телефона, кроме того номер телефона может варьировать в зависимости от способа набора.

Я использую такой запросик:

```
ContactInfo lookupContactInfo(Context context, String phoneNumber) {
    ContactInfo contactInfo=null;
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
    String[] projection = new String[] {ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID,
            ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.LOOKUP_KEY,
            ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.LAST_TIME_CONTACTED};

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, "last_time_contacted desc");
    if(cursor!=null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        contactInfo = new ContactInfo();
        contactInfo.name = cursor.getString(0);
        contactInfo.id = cursor.getString(1);
        contactInfo.key = cursor.getString(2);
        contactInfo.phone=phoneNumber;
    }
    if(cursor!=null)
        cursor.close();
    return contactInfo;
}
```

`ContactInfo` - это небольшая структурка с самоочевидными полями (ясно из кода какими). Фишка этого кода в том, что он выдает данные контакта базируясь на последних данных ("last_time_contacted desc").

Запрос небыстрый посему его надо сажать на `AsyncTask`. Рекомендуется номер телефона соответствующим образом нормализовать - иначе могут быть сюрпризы. Правда, если ищется номер телефона входящего адресата (поле `address`) - то там номер уже нормализованный.